# How to suppress false positives in Fortify

Tags: fortify

I have two questions regarding Fortify.

1 -  Lets say I have a windows forms app, which asks for a username
and password, and the name of the textbox for password is
texboxPassword. So in the designer file, you have the following,
generated by the designer.

> ```
> // 
> // texboxPassword
> // 
> this.texboxPassword.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, 163);
> this.texboxPassword.Name = "texboxPassword";
> this.texboxPassword.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 73);
> this.texboxPassword.TabIndex = 3;
> ```

Fortify marks this as a password in comment issue. How can I suppress this by creating a custom rule? I don't want to suppress the whole issue because I still would like to catch certain patterns (such as password followed by = or : in comments) but the blanket search where any line that contains password is flagged is creating so many false positives. I looked into creating a structural rule but could not figure out how to remove the associated tag (where can I find the tag for password in comment anyways?)

2 - Let's say I have a custom UI control. This control html encodes everything and in my context, it is good enough to avoid XSS. Needless to say, it is being flagged by Fortify. How can I suppress XSS when I have a certain control type in my UI and all of its methods are safe for XSS (they sanitize) in my context? I have tried a DataflowCleanseRule (with a label just to test the concept) and wanted to mark get_Text() and set_Text() as sanitizer functions, but it did not make a difference and Fortify still flagged it for XSS.

```
<DataflowCleanseRule formatVersion="3.16" language="dotnet">
                <RuleID>0D495522-BA81-440E-B191-48A67D9092BE</RuleID>
                <TaintFlags>+VALIDATED_CROSS_SITE_SCRIPTING_REFLECTED,+VALIDATED_CROSS_SITE_SCRIPTING_PERSISTENT,+VALIDATED_CROSS_SITE_SCRIPTING_DOM,+VALIDATED_CROSS_SITE_SCRIPTING_POOR_VALIDATION</TaintFlags>
                <FunctionIdentifier>
                    <NamespaceName>
                        <Pattern>System.Web.UI.WebControls</Pattern>
                    </NamespaceName>
                    <ClassName>
                        <Pattern>Label</Pattern>
                    </ClassName>
                    <FunctionName>
                        <Pattern>_Text</Pattern>
                    </FunctionName>
                    <ApplyTo implements="true" overrides="true" extends="true"/>
                </FunctionIdentifier>
                <OutArguments>return</OutArguments>
            </DataflowCleanseRule>
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This is parsed using regular expressions. Unless you think you are able to create a regular expression that can parse human language properly, I would leave it alone and just audit it as not an issue.
2. The Pattern tag uses a java regular expression in the body, so should be used as user2867433 suggested. However, you stated

> This control html encodes everything and in my context, it is good enough to avoid XSS

If you are going to use a custom rule, this has to assume that it will work in EVERY context, as say in the future somebody writes a piece of code that uses get_Text and then places this directly into a piece of JavaScript, html encoding will do NOTHING to stop the XSS problem here. I would advise again to audit this as not an issue or a false positive due to the validation used and explain why it's good enough in that context

Comment: Thank you, I ended up leaving them alone and audit as not issues

Comment: Hi all! What if the "not an issue" start to be too many (huge codebase and every time we deploy it is really a waste of time to repeat all the old "not an issue" again)? Is there a way to make the items marked as "not an issue" permanently so?

Answer (score 0):

Within "Pattern" you can use Java-Regex. So it should work if you use [gs]et_Text